# Anybody succeeded in converting cocos2d 2.x to winobjc?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, winobjc

I am trying to convert my cocos2d 2.x of iPhone projects to windows 10, but failed in compiling for many errors.

Are there any developers who have succeeded in doing so?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please add more information to your compilation issues?

Comment: Hi, Thank you! But there are too many errors. I have just given it up for the time being, since I feel that the bridge to iOS is still far from practice.

Comment: I think it would be greatly helpful for both of the developers and MS himself if cocos2d-iphone games can be ported to Windows 10, because there are huge number of great games that developed with it. I would like to see that MS would take the initial step to do it, or demonstrate that he has done it!